# git show for merges in TortoiseGit

Tags: git, merge, tortoisegit, git-show

If I call `git show XYZ` on a merge in the console, I only see the diff of the conflicting files. gitg, and I guess also many other graphical tools, are showing the same diff on selecting a commit. TortoiseGit is showing a diff to each parent instead.

**How do I get the output of `git show` for a merge in TortoiseGit?**

Edit:
By default `git` uses the `--combined` option on `diff` and `show`. Tortoise is using `-m` as default to display a diff to each parent.

Answer (score 0):

Select the commit -> right click -> `Unified Diff with` -> `Only Merged Files`

Comment: This is not the same. `Only merged files` is showing more. I.e. if I have a conflictless (empty ) merge `git show` displays no diff and `Only merged files` shows some more (Sorry, can't copy the real commit here, but I will create a minimal sample later).